# Cannot set property 'src' of null when using variable source

Tags: javascript, html, image, error-handling, variable-declaration

I saw that this question was asked many times and I've been looking in every single one for a solution but couldn't find one for my specific problem. I'm composing a link using different strings and variables and I would like to fill in a table with images. So far, in most of the threads that tackle this problem, I can see the following strategy:

```
document.getElementById('ID').src = variablewithlink;
```

or even this:

```
document.querySelector('img').src = variablewithlink;
```

Inserted in the html as:

```
<img id="ID" src="" width="100" height="70";/>
```

And that's what I used in my code, but it still gives

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
```

When I'm logging the variable using `alert`, it shows the links that contain the images, but when reading it in the `<img>` tag, it gives that error. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? The code is given below:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCg9wsEL5tAYdSyz9IapqvvMGWpFNAlc74",
      authDomain: "checkup-7b62e.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://checkup-7b62e.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "checkup-7b62e",
      storageBucket: "checkup-7b62e.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "324802643995"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>

  <head>
  </head>
  <table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
    <tr id="tr">
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Text</th>
  </table>

  <script>
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref("-Events").orderByKey().limitToLast(5).once('value', function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          val = data.val();
          link_for_picture = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/checkup-7b62e.appspot.com/o/" + val.imageUrl.split("/")[3] + "?alt=media";
          document.getElementById('image').src = link_for_picture;
          alert(link_for_picture);
          content += '<tr>';
          content += '<td>' + '<img id="image" src=link_for_picture border={0} height={150} width={150}></img>' + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + val.headline + '</td>';
          content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#ex-table').append(content);
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because there is no `<img id="image">` in your html.

Comment: What about this: ``content += '<td>' + '<img id="image" src=link_for_picture border={0} height={150} width={150}></img>' + '</td>'`` in the script? Doesn't that go as HTML?

Comment: oh, you forgot to concatenate variable `'<img id="image" src='+link_for_picture+' border={0}'`

Comment: and you have multiple `id=image`. Id must be unique. http://jsfiddle.net/Smollet92/dwx1mb4a/1/

Comment: Oh, wow. That was a quick-fix after sooo long. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: And about that concatination. I recomend you to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Reading now. Had no idea about it. Thanks a lot. If you would like to add a bit of explanation and the solution as an answer, I would gladly vote it as the right answer. I've been spending many hours to try to figure this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forgot to concatenate variable `<img id="image" src='+link_for_picture+' border={0}`. Using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) will prevent this kind of errors.
2. You have that *src of null* error because you're trying to get to the element `img` **before** appending it to the HTML.
3. Last and most common rookie mistake: in that loop you create multiple elements with same id. But id must be unique.

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/Smollet92/dwx1mb4a/4/ (because SO snippet is giving script error for some reason)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I will also change the ID's of each elements.

Answer (score 0):

It could also happen if you try to assign a value to a property that is not build yet. Placing the script link just before  instead of  will solve the problem.